# Changing BootstrapVue scss variables in Nuxt

Tags: sass, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to customize the 'primary' color in the BootstrapVue scss environment which I use in my Nuxt project.
I've checked several resources (such as https://dev.to/paramo/using-sass-global-variables-in-nuxt-js-j0k and https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/reference/theming). However, I haven't succeeded.

This is what I've already done up to the moment:
1)created a file @/assets/scss/customTheme.scss:

```
$primary: #00BFA5;
```

2)installed sass, sass-loader and @nuxtjs/style-resources

3)set a nuxt configuration:

```
modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth-next',
    ['nuxt-mq'],
    'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
    '@nuxtjs/proxy',
    '@nuxtjs/style-resources'        
],
styleResources: {
    scss: ['@/assets/scss/*.scss']
},
css: [
    '@/assets/scss/customTheme.scss'
]
```

I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Set bootstrapVue module like below, in your `nuxt.config.js`

```
modules: [
     ['bootstrap-vue/nuxt', { css: false }]
],
```

and set your custom css like below:

```
css: [
    '~/assets/scss/style.scss'
  ],
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this solution is not relevant for me since I don't want to disable all BootstrapVue styling, just one variable. While in this case, I will need to set all css settings by myself.

Comment: I guess you forgot to write that my .scss file should be updated - bootstrapvue styling should be imported.